# Ошибка при компиляции любого проекта в Code::Blocks

Tags: c, компилятор, компиляция, c++, codeblocks

Установил новую версию Code::Blocks 12.11; захотел запустить старый проект - и тут мне выдает ошибку!
Я сначала не понял в  чем дело, подумал, что что-то где-то в коде не то. Смотрю в логи - нет, код в порядке. 
Не понимая в чем дело, написал простейший код. Запускаю - все равно ошибка! При чем одна и таже!

Вот Build Log:

> mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\LOL.exe
> obj\Debug\main.o     c:/program
> files/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> cannot open output file
> bin\Debug\LOL.exe: Permission denied
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
> exit status Process terminated with
> status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds) 1
> errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0
> seconds)

Вот текст ошибки:

> ld.exe||cannot open output file
> bin\Debug\LOL.exe Permission denied|
> ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0
> warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|

Кто может подсказать, в чем проблема???

Я не могу ничего запустить!!! Приходится пока на VS2012 сидеть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вы пытаетесь сбилдить файл, который уже запущен. Проверьте в списках процессов в диспетчере задач. Если не ошибаюсь, в CodeBlocks есть такая особенность - если вы создаете консольное приложение, а потом закрываете его, нажав на "крестик" в правом верхнем углу, то может возникнуть проблема, что вы описали.
Либо самый очевидный вариант - у вас нет прав на запись в папку

Comment: нет, запущен только один процесс. Только что это проверил

Comment: ну тогда самый очевидный вариант - у вас нет прав на запись в папку

Comment: Большое спасибо! 
Действительно, все гениальное - просто! 
Оказывается, что бы ошибки не было, нужно запускать Code::Blocks от имени администратора (все время). Поэтмоу просто в свойствах программы выставить права администратора. И все!

Comment: Большое пожалуйста. Правда, благодарить вам в первую очередь нужно себя - до этой идеи вы додумались, надо полагать,сами)